# python extract entries from a list based from keywords in a dictionary

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to filter laptop entries only from a list (productUrl.txt) and save it in a seperate text file (laptop.txt)

My code:

```
ddic = ['Intel', 'AMD', 'Ryzen', 'lenovo', 'chuwi', 'huawei']
laptop = []
file2 =open('./output/productUrl.txt','r')
url = file2.readlines()

count = 0
for line in url:
    count += 1
    if any(keyword in url for keyword in ddic):
        laptop = url
        print(laptop, sep="\n", file=open('./output/laptop.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8'))
file2.close
```

The productUrl.txt contains entries like this:

```
www.lazada.com.ph/products/chuwi-mijabook-intel-celeron-n3450-3k-display-i2194877054-s9863142699.html?search=1
www.lazada.com.ph/products/hot-selling-ovation-breeze-25-sataiii-120gb-240gb-480gb-ssd-i2320715371-s10522178610.html?search=1
www.lazada.com.ph/products/huawei-matebook-14-laptop-2k-fullview-display-amd-ryzen-4000-h-series-16gb-ram-512gb-ssd-i1262976645-s10442000469.html?search=1
www.lazada.com.ph/products/hot-selling-kingston-a2000-250gb-m2-2280-nvme-pcie-internal-ssd-solid-state-drive-sa2000m8250g-i2320553660-s10521592342.html?search=1
www.lazada.com.ph/products/lenovo-legion-5-series-r7000-r7000p-2021-brand-new-gaming-laptop-series-156-165hz-16gb-ram-512gb-ssd-i1889528550-s9658830606.html?search=1
```

the expected result is a text file called laptop.txt containing the ff.

```
www.lazada.com.ph/products/chuwi-mijabook-intel-celeron-n3450-3k-display-i2194877054-s9863142699.html?search=1
www.lazada.com.ph/products/huawei-matebook-14-laptop-2k-fullview-display-amd-ryzen-4000-h-series-16gb-ram-512gb-ssd-i1262976645-s10442000469.html?search=1
www.lazada.com.ph/products/lenovo-legion-5-series-r7000-r7000p-2021-brand-new-gaming-laptop-series-156-165hz-16gb-ram-512gb-ssd-i1889528550-s9658830606.html?search=1
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: This is overkill for a python script. Just use grep.

Comment: `if any(keyword in url for keyword in ddic)` I think you meant this to be `keyword in line` instead.

Comment: Hi wim, thank you for your comment. Can you paste the exact codes to achive the expected result? I'm new to phython, I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I may change your code. You can focus on the `if` inside `for`

```
for line in url:
    if [brand for brand in ddic if brand in line]:
        laptop.append(line)
        print(line, sep="\n", file=open('./output/laptop.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8'))
file2.close
```

Comment: This doesn't work I got error:
  File "c:\Users\nate\Documents\Python\LazadaScapper\test.py", line 8
    if [for brand in ddic if brand in line]:     
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

but thank you for your answer

Comment: Oh sorry I have update the `if` condition. Now it's okay.

Answer (score 0):

```
ddic = ['Intel', 'AMD', 'Ryzen', 'lenovo', 'chuwi', 'huawei']
laptop = []

file2 =open('./output/productUrl.txt','r').read()
data=file2.split("\n")

laptop=[i for i in data for j in ddic if j in i]
print(laptop)
```